# is there a way bulk single files to zip?

Tags: compression, zip

we have some thousands of files in a folder, and the software that runs it now allows to read from compressed folders, but only 1 large file per compressed folder

is there any software that would allow us to just select the main folder automatically compress them individually?

we've tried the popular compressing software (k zip, g zip, 7 zip, win rar) and maybe there's an option for this that we just missed, so if you can also provide some instructions it be great

thanks

(goes without saying free would be better)

Comment: You want to compress all files of the sub-folders of a main folder into zip files, 1 zip file for each sub-folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be the expected result?

[image]

You can create a batch file by copying the following code to notepad and save the file with the name that you want but with a *.bat extension. Next you drag and drop the main folder to the bat file. At set Seven= you put the path to 7z.exe file...

```
@echo off

:: Put path to 7z.exe here:
set Seven=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe

IF exist "%~1" (IF /i not exist "%~1\" exit) else (exit)

pushd "%~1"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.*') do (
                                           "%Seven%" a -tzip -sdel "%%~na.zip" "%%a"
                                           If /i exist "%%~a" RD /q /s "%%~a"
                                          )
```

Try it on a copy first to see if it is really what you want...

Comment: hey, thanks. There's no sub-folders. just the Main folder with all the individual files that must be individually packaged.

Comment: That is even easier, please see my updated answer...

Comment: that's perfect. thank you!